# Calculating the amount of numbers in a range that yields a certain condition

Tags: combinatorics

For example:
How many numbers in $[40000,70000]$ are there such that the sum of all digits is $12$ and the right most digit is $1$?
I cant figure out how to calculate the numbers that the sum of thier digits gives $12$.
Hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Rephrase: how many tuples $(d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4,d_5)\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}^5$ exist that satisfy the following conditions:

- $d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5=12$
- $d_1\in\{4,5,6,7\}$
- $d_5=1$

This asks for an application of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)):

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Inclusion-exclusion principle and the method to count the number of $k$-tuples of non-negative integers with a certain sum.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's equal to the following problem:

How many numbers between 4000 and 6999 have the sum of digits equal to 11. If we denote $P(m,n)$ as the total number of numbers less than $n$ having sum of digits equal to $m$, the problem will turn to calculation of:

$$P(11-4,999)+P(11-5,999)+P(11-6,999).$$

But what is the $P(m,999)$ for $m<10$. It's the number of ways to put $m$ balls in 3 boxes. So $P(m,999) = C_{m+2}^{2}$. The remaining work is simple:

$$P(11-4,999)+P(11-5,999)+P(11-6,999) = C_{9}^{2}+C_{8}^{2}+C_{7}^{2}$$